# TAniIndicator for VCL

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

I started using Firemonkey in Delphi XE 10 Seatle, and I really enjoyed the TAniIndicator. Is there an equivalent for the VCL? How can I generate the same effect on a VCL application? We have the TAnimate, but all it has are Windows animations.
Tks

Comment: You can use an AVI file with `TAnimate`. Find a 3rd party animation you like, or make your own.

Comment: I did consider the possibility of creating the animation, but I thought that there'd might be a simpler solution that didn't envolve learning to make animations, or hunting down a similar animation. Tks anyways Remy.

Comment: Seattle and above have TActivityIndicator. Will that work?

Comment: Yeah, sure.. It's exactly what I needed. I didn't know this component. I'm coming from Delphi 2009. Please, post it as the answer.
I don't understand the down votes. It's a legitimate question.

Comment: That's just a progress bar isn't it?

Comment: No. It's similar to the javascripts loading, with a circle, and an animation like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lO45DNkBMi4

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where I need to use the component, I don't have the room for a big progress bar. I needed the round loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 10 Seattle and above include some Windows 10 style components, some of which also work on Windows 7 and 8.x. One of those is the [TActivityIndicator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TActivityIndicator), which you can find on the Windows 10 palette page. There's also a sample of its use available in the Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\ActivityIndicator folder.

Comment: Thank you. I'm migrating from Delphi 2009, and I didn't know this component. I searched with different types of names, and I couldn't get anything searching with Google. I thought there might be sometime simpler than generating an AVI with the loading animation. Don't understand the down votes. I hold this help anything searching for the same thing.